# Turtle Window issue

Tags: python-3.x

I am running into an issue after I close the window after running the code below. The program runs smoothly, draws a recursive pattern and exits when I click close, however, the program window pauses and I have to force shut it down which also closes the kernel and restarts the kernel. What could be causing this?

```
import turtle

myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myWin = turtle.Screen()

def drawSpiral(myTurtle, lineLen):
    if lineLen > 0:
    myTurtle.forward(lineLen)
    myTurtle.right(90)
    drawSpiral(myTurtle,lineLen-5)

drawSpiral(myTurtle,100)
myWin.exitonclick()
```